# 16 Names of Lord Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, name

In the following verse, 16 names of Vishnu given and mentioned that on which occasion/activity we should chant which name.

> **Aushadhe Chintayét *Vishnum* Bhojané cha *Janardanam*
>
>   Shayane *Padmanabham* cha Vivahé cha *Prajapatim***
>
> While taking any Medicine one should remember - Lord *Vishnu* .While Consuming food one should remember – Lord *Janardana*;While Sleeping one should  remember – Lord *Padmanabha*, During wedding one should remember –  lord *Prajapati*
>
> **Yudhe *Chakradharam* Devam Pravase cha *Trivikramam*
>
>   *Naraayanam* Tanur-tyagé *Sreedharam* Priya-sangamé**
>
> At war one should remember – Lord *Chakradhari*, While Traveling one should remember – Lord *Trivikrama*.Death bed one should remember – Lord *Narayana*, when meeting your loved ones remember– Lord *Sreedhara*.
>
> **Du-swapne Smara *Govindam* Sankate *Madhusoodanam*
>
>   Kaanane *Naarasimham* cha Paavake *Jalashaayinam***
>
> When having Bad dreams one should remember - Lord *Govinda* , While in trouble times one should remember– Lord *Madhusoodana*;While In a forest one should remember - Lord *Narasimha*, In the midst of fire One should remember - Lord *Jalashayina*
>
> **Jalamadhye *Varaham* cha Parvate *Raghunandanam*
>
>   Gamane *Vamanam* chaiva Sarva-kaaryeshu *Madhavam***
>
> In the middle of water (water activities or travel ) one should remember –  Lord *Varaha*, On a mountain (trekking) one should remember – Lord *Raghunandana* (Lord Rama). While Travel by foot one should remember – Lord *Vamana*, when you start any deed remember - Lord *Madhava*.
>
> **Shodashaitaani Naamani Pratarudhaya ya: padeth
>
>   Sarva-papa-vinirmukhto Vishnu-loke Maheeyate**
>
> One who reads all of these 16 names every morning ,then he will get rid of all the sins and will attain Loka(Moksha) or Heaven.

What I want to know is, why certain names for certain activities. I know reason of some name i.e. Vamana (we should chant while traveling on foot) who use to travel on feet and did cover all lokas with only two steps. So it makes sense that doing dhyanA of Vamana will make traveling on feet benificial. And Varaha (while in water one should do dhayana of Vraha)  also makes sense to me because He saved Earth from ocean, he protect Earth from water, hence he is savior if we are in water (my guess). But not all names makes sense to me because I am not aware about those names. So what's the reason behind those names on those conditions/activities?

Comment: Medicine - Lord Vishnu - Vishnu is preserver (of life).

Sleeping - Lord Padmanabha - Padmanabha is in sleeping posture.

Wedding – Lord Prajapati - Prajapati is creator (of life).

War – Lord Chakradhari - Chakra is ultimate weapon.

Mountain - Lord Raghunandana - Rama's Bhaktha Hanuman could easily lift even a mountain.